# Sample ANT Build script for the command

Tags: javascript, ant, compression

I'm new to ANT Scripting. I need the ANT Script to achieve the below functionality.

```
C:\dojo-release-1.4.2-shrinksafe>java -jar shrinksafe.jar  C:\Build\JS\*.js  >  testMin.js
```

Above command merges all JS files in that folder to a single one.

```
<java jar="shrinksafe.jar" fork="true" output="testMin.js">
    <arg value="*C:\Build\JS\*.js"/>
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="js.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</java>
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct implementation of this. I'm getting the error

```
js: Couldn't open file "C:\Build\JS\*.js"
```

Can someone please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk in "*.js" is sent literally to the Java class and not expanded as it might have been when entered on the command line.

I suggest you join the files first using the **concat** task and then run shrinksafe on the resulting file.